# mutate function shows new column created in data viewer, but not in dataframe in environment

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm running into a problem where I have mutated a new column

```
lowCOXdata %>%
  mutate(IL1bLoworHigh = case_when(Adjusted.Average..IL1b < 2.30 | Adjusted.Average..IL1b == NA ~ 1,
      Adjusted.Average..IL1b > 2.30 ~ 2)
  )
```

called IL1bLoworHigh in dataframe called lowCOXdata, and what's strange is that the new column is created and shown in the data viewer, but not the environment and data frame. In the data viewer, it says that the number of columns is 9, but on the right hand side in the environment the number of variables is 8. See picture below:
[9 columns on the left side but only 8 variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pm7S.png)

Comment: Can you show a sample of your data frame as an example? You can use `dput` to regenerate your data frame. This way, we can easily copy and check your dataset

Comment: You have to assign results to modify objects. If `x <- 1`, `x + 1` shows `2` but `x` is unchanged. `x <- x + 1` to modify `x`. `lowCOXdata <- lowCOXdata %>% mutate...` to modify the object.

Comment: Also, `== NA` is an antipattern. Use `is.na()` instead, change to `Adjusted.Average..IL1b < 2.30 | is.na(Adjusted.Average..IL1b) ~ 1`.